# Where is Play Framework 2 home directory?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've just installed the play framework(latest version) using the typesafe activator method of installation.
Now I want to create an intellij idea play 2 project and the ide is asking me about play 2 home directory.
Where exactly does play 2 installs itself when I run the activator?
My operating system is mac os mountain lion.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create an app, you can find more info here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication

and importing your app to intelliJ is also easy, look at the link below, but before that install scala  and play 2.0 plugins on your IntelliJ

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE